# How can I use anchor with canvas menu?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have this code:

```html
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">

      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label class="first">Foundation</label></li>
        <li><a href="http://foundation.zurb.com/index.html">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>

      <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label class="first">Learn</label></li>
        <li><a href="#main">Anchor1</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>
```

I'd like to click on `Anchor1` link and to close the canvas menu after the webpage scrolls to right anchor.

How can I do that?

--

I have found to close canvas-menu :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('a[href="#anchor1"]').click(function() { 
   $(".menu-wrap").removeClass("move-right");       
   });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just saw this question when I was running into the same problem.

Actually Foundation provides an option for this which you can set to true:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html#optional-javascript-configuration

```
$(document).foundation({
  offcanvas : {
    // Sets method in which offcanvas opens.
    // [ move | overlap_single | overlap ]
    open_method: 'move', 
    // Should the menu close when a menu link is clicked?
    // [ true | false ]
    close_on_click : false
  }
});
```